# How can I escape the slash character in vi?

Tags: escaping, find, editor, vi

When I try to search a string starting with the slash / character in **vi**, the cursor jumps to the next search result from the previous search. However, I'd like to find the literal slash character. How can this be done?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Type this:

```
/\/
```

Answer (score 6):

You would not need to escape `/` if you use `?`

```
?/home/my_user/ # and enter to search backwards
/               # and enter to search forwards
```

See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_without_need_to_escape_slash).

Answer (score 4):

Use a backslash.

```
:/\/
```

This will search forward to the next forward slash.

Comment: Ah...yes you are right. But it doesn't hurt either. Thanks for the tip though!

Answer (score 2):

I spent too much time on this, so let me put the quick answer here.  The escape char in vi (vim also, I think, I am using a CentOS box here) is "\", as per lutz's answer from 8 years ago.  I have this stuff that was built in Windows, am converting to Linux. Typically, you might have a file with absolute directory locations, and you want to convert the slashes from "\yatta\yatta\blah..." to "/yatta/yatta/blah...", all occurances in all lines.  For vi, all lines is %s, and the trailing g means all occurances within each line.  So, edit your file with vi or vim, and press escape and colon to get the ":" prompt, and enter:

```
%s/\\/\//g
```

All the "\" chars get changed to "/".  But you may still need to change the "c:" references to "/home/prod" or something like that, to sit in front of "/yatta/yatta/blah...".  Easy.  The vi escape char is "\", so you press esc, and enter ":" to jump to vi cmd entry mode, and enter:

```
%s/c:/\/home\/prod/g
```

There are lots of quicky "cheat-sheets" of vi/vim commands available.  It is a ubiquitous tool, available on virtually every Linux/Unix system - even on jailbroken iPads and such.

Answer (score 0):

--- oops, sorry, I entered info for replace.  Escaping with \ is better for search only

Use a different separator

```
:%s./.z.
```

will replace all '/' with the letter z